# How to extend SpaCy English model with domain-specific rules?

Tags: spacy, python-packaging

I am using SpaCy for NLP tasks on English text from a unique subject domain.  I'd like to make gradual improvements to SpaCy's extant English model (specifically I'm starting from `'en_core_web_md'`), and package them for easy re-use by my colleagues.

My first change is a simple change to the tokenizer; I've started by defining a custom class:

```
class DomainSpecificEnglish(English.Defaults):
    lang = 'en_mydomain'

    class Defaults(English.Defaults):
        # my custom changes the tokenizer here


spacy.util.set_lang_class(DomainSpecificEnglish.lang, DomainSpecificEnglish)
```

For now, I would continue to use `en_core_web_md`'s Vocab and word vectors (later I will re-train these too). , but SpaCy looks these up model files via the `lang` string, which is no longer `"en"`.

How can I build a domain-specific "language" subclass that relies upon already-built models? Do I have to explicitly copy the `en_core_web_md` files to a new folder on disk named `en_mydomain`?

Once that works, I'm hoping to package this tiny project (the one class) as a Python egg that my colleagues can install.  Ideally I shouldn't require them to also run extra post-installation commands to move files around on disk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [docs](https://spacy.io/docs/usage/models#usage), you can create a link like so:

```
python -m spacy link en_core_web_md en_mydomain
```

This just creates a symlink, so no files are copied and it completes immediately.

Comment: This does load the model successfully, but it also happens to break `spacy.load`.  I've reported this at https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/issues/1366
Yours is probably the correct answer but I may wait for follow-up on that GH issue to make sure they aren't recommending doing it differently.

Comment: Best to create the custom language with `spacy package` and explicitly override `meta.json` to reference your new language name.